# If I create a project to react native how to make it support on several Android platforms for example (Android 6 and later)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in the world of APP(mobile applications). I want to create a APP using react native. But it is necessary that it works out in several versions of android (6 onwards).

Now I am working on no expo way and on windows 10 too. So,  I installed react native that now it works with android 9 (PIE) API LVL 28 AVD. If I finish my project with this API, would the apk work on different old versions of Android? or only in phones which have API 9. Give me advices pleases.

if i development my project with react native 0.61.5 version (the last i think 18/02/2020), would i run old APIs of android (6 onwards i want)?. Or, do i need to put my react native version on an old version to development an APP on android 6 to run on several versions?. Or the only thing that i need to do is write a sentence in my code that cover some plataforms.

PD: I'm new in this web page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set your minSDK in the Android project. To do so, open up your build.gradle in the Android portion of your project and then change minSDK to whatever version you need. IIRC React Native supports all the way back to API 19 and Android 6 is API 21. If it's already low enough, no need to change it. That being said, I'd still recommend testing on multiple phones.

Comment: HOOO my friend you are right, thanks for your answere. But in my  buildscript is this code, Doesn't it matter if buildTooldVerion is on 28?.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }

Comment: @abdiaslabrador Glad I could help. The other vars do not matter (at least for now); they're about what version is used for building and editing code. I'd suggest keeping them until you need to change them. And IIRC = If I remember correctly

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question @abdiaslabrador, you want your app to be available to users still on android version 5.1 to 8.1 and to do that you have to select an Android API level lower than level 29 which targets only android phones running Android10. For your case, that'd be android API level 22 which enables you target android version 5.1 (lollipop) and above. Check out the official android [build numbers](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) page for more clarification

Comment: @abdiaslabrador if this answers your question, kindly accept to help others with similar questions

Comment: And... Don't i need to put my react native version back (old version that matches to android 6) or only if i select my target i will work out?.

Comment: Don't worry about your react-native version, select the minimum API level that satifies your requirements and you're set